# List<int> filtering using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a List object which contains Id values for example it contains:
1,2,10,1,23,11,1,4,2,2,.. etc  I need to find out how many times "1","2",... etc  have occured
using Linq in C#

kindly help.

Comment: In fairness I'd used a lot Wheres, Joins, etc. before I found out about GroupBy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's pretty simple using [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx):

```
var grouped = list.GroupBy(x => x);

foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} appears {1} times", group.Key, group.Count());
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
var query = list.GroupBy(x => x, (x, g) => new { Key = x, Count = g.Count() }));

foreach (var result in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} appears {1} times", result.Key, result.Count);
}
```

(The difference is just in when we transform the group into a result, really.)

Answer (score 12):

Use [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx):

```
var les = new[] { 1, 2, 10, 1, 23, 11, 1, 4, 2, 2 };

var result = les
    .GroupBy(i => i, (e, g) => new { Value = e, Count = g.Count() });
```

Or using alternative syntax:

```
var result =
    from i in les
    group i by i
    into g
    select new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 var l = new List<int> {1,2,10,1,23,11,1,4,2,2};
 l.GroupBy(i => i)
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(g => Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", g.Key, g.Count()));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 10, 1, 23, 11, 1, 4, 2, 2, };
var groups = list.GroupBy(i => i);
foreach (var group in groups)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} occurs {1} times", group.Key, group.Count());
```