# comparison operator not supported for type int[] - linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq

Here is the problematic line:

```
var originalSummaryCandidates = 
    (from a in masterDB.tbl_thirty_second_summaries_multi_variant_associations
     join d in masterDB.tbl_thirty_second_summaries_multi_variants on a.ThirtySecSummaryId equals d.ThirtySecondSummaryId_this
     where d.DrugId == drugId &&                                                       
     variantGenotypeIds.Contains(new int[] {a.VariantId, a.GenotypeId})
     select d.ThirtySecondSummaryId_this)
   .Distinct()
   .ToList();
```

variantGeotpeIds is of type `List<int[]>`. Both a.VariantId and a.GenotypeId are of type int.

I cannot figure out why it why it will not do the comparison. Is this a deferred execution issue? It doesn't seem like it should be...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `List<int>.Contains(int[])` looks suspicious - are you trying to determine if _both_ values are contained in the list?

Comment: I made a mistake. I will edit the original post. It should be List<int[]>.Contains(int[])

Comment: If you are looking to compare `int[]` I think the `List<T>.Any()` Method could be what you're looking for Any() returns a boolean so I don't think that it's what's needed but here is a good link that explains http://www.dotnetperls.com/any or `Jon Skeets` example would be something that looks like it would works for `List<int[]>` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548005/listint-filtering-using-linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<T>.Contains` only takes a single parameter of type `T`. In your case, `T` is `Int32` but you're passing in a `Int32[]`.

If you want to check that both values are in the list, you have to break the calls apart:

```
where d.DrugId == drugId &&
    variantGenotypeIds.Contains(a.VariantId) &&
    variantGenotypeIds.Contains(a.GenotypeId)
```

**EDIT**

If `variantGenotypeIds` is actually a `List<Int32[]>`, then there's another issue. LINQ to SQL will try to convert your query into its SQL equivalent. In this case, there's no way to translate your query into SQL so LINQ to SQL will throw an Exception.

If you really need to query this way, you'll have to read the records into memory first and then query using LINQ to Objects (which may or may not be a big deal depending on how many rows you are reading):

```
var query = 
    from a in masterDB.tbl_thirty_second_summaries_multi_variant_associations
    join d in masterDB.tbl_thirty_second_summaries_multi_variants 
    on a.ThirtySecSummaryId equals d.ThirtySecondSummaryId_this
    where d.DrugId == drugId
    select new { a, d }

var originalSummaryCandidates =
    (from q in query.AsEnumerable()
     where variantGenotypeIds.Contains(new [] { q.a.VariantId, q.a.GenotypeId})
     select d.ThirtySecondSummaryId_this)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. variantGenotypeIds is of type List<Int[]>

Comment: Ok thanks so how would I do that? I have a list<ObjectType> in memory and now I want all the records where new int[] {Object.id1, Object.id2} is contained in a List<int[]>

Comment: @Byc - I updated with the code. I usually don't use query syntax and I don't have a compiler to test anything, so it might not be 100% correct.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. It had one mistake but was otherwise compiler error free. Unfortunately, I am still getting the error: comparison operators not supported for int[]

Comment: @Byc - I forgot to add the call to `AsEnumerable()` on `query` in the second statement. And if that doesn't work, you can for execution on the first and call `ToList()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Array comparison uses *reference* equality by default.  It's *possible* that linq-to-sql just tries to translate that into SQL that compares the values, but you'd have to look at the generated SQL to be sure.  Another option would be to use `Any` instead:

```
 where d.DrugId == drugId &&                                                       
 variantGenotypeIds.Any(v => v[0] == a.VariantId && v[1] == a.GenotypeId)
```

but I'm not sure if Linq-to-Sql will be able to translate that to the correct SQL either.  Another option would be to project the List` to a > and then do a string comparison:

```
variantGenotypeStrings = variantGenotypeIds.Select(v => string.Format("{0}|{1}", v[0],v[1]);

var originalSummaryCandidates = 
    (from a in masterDB.tbl_thirty_second_summaries_multi_variant_associations
     join d in masterDB.tbl_thirty_second_summaries_multi_variants on a.ThirtySecSummaryId equals d.ThirtySecondSummaryId_this
     where d.DrugId == drugId &&                                                       
     variantGenotypeStrings.Contains(string.Format("{0}|{1}", a.VariantId, a.GenotypeId))
     select d.ThirtySecondSummaryId_this)
   .Distinct()
   .ToList();
```

Comment: hmmm, interesting. Yeah, I am pretty sure I tried using Any and it could not be converted into the SQL. I will give the string comparison trick a try. It seems like it should work. Thanks.